# Create file in Google Cloud Storage with python

Tags: google-cloud-storage

This is the method that i used to save a new file in Google Cloud Storage

```
cloud_storage_path = "/gs/[my_app_name].appspot.com/%s/%s" % (user_key.id(), img_title)
    blobstore_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(cloud_storage_path)
    cloud_storage_file = cloudstorage_api.open(
        filename=cloud_storage_path, mode="w", content_type=img_type
    )
    cloud_storage_file.write(img_content)
    cloud_storage_file.close()
```

But when execute this method. The log file printed :

```
Path should have format /bucket/filename but got /gs/[my_app_name].appspot.com/6473924464345088/background.jpg
```

PS: i changed [my_app_name]  and, [my_app_name].appspot.com is my bucket name

So, what will I do next in this case ?
I can not save the file to that path

Comment: Have you tried removing the "/gs"?

Comment: I did, but this error appears:
`filename must start with "/gs/": /[my_app_name].appspot.com/6473924464345088/background.jpg

Comment: Hrm....does it work without the last "/"? Maybe that needs escaping?

Comment: i tried so many way but alway failed

Comment: did you ever found the way? I am trying to write files into it, but nothing seems to be working